# Accidently deleted partition now stuck in grub error: unknown filesystem

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

I accidently deleted a partition from windows and restarted now it boots in grub with

```
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

How can I get my PC to boot from windows loader instead of grub? Entering ls and set into grub I get

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos51)
```

and

```
grub rescue> set
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos5
```

if that helps.

Comment: BIOS or UEFI. With partitions shown as msdos, should be BIOS. You just need to use your Windows repair flash drive and run from repair console fixMBR. How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of the [Ultimate Boot Cd](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) and boot your Pc with that. 
Launch "Parted Magic"  from the menu
When the boot completes, launch "TestDisk" from the menu. 
Follow the on-screen instructions to perform a quick scan of the drive in question. It's not quick but does usually work. It can scan for "lost" partitions by looking for markers common to the different file system types then offer to repair the MBR based on what it finds.